# Compare Persian characters in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have two Persian word are the same, but they do not match together, why?
What do i do for match them together in php.(Of course, this is an example)

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/u5sUa

```
    $wordd1='فريدونكنار';
    $wordm2='فریدونکنار';
    if($wordd1 == $wordm2){
        echo 'ok'; //i want this result
    }else{
        echo 'no';
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Those strings appear similar, but they are not equal!

The first string contains the characters:

```
U+641  'ف'  ARABIC LETTER FEH
U+631  'ر'  ARABIC LETTER REH
U+64A  'ي'  ARABIC LETTER YEH       <- 1
U+62F  'د'  ARABIC LETTER DAL
U+648  'و'  ARABIC LETTER WAW
U+646  'ن'  ARABIC LETTER NOON
U+643  'ك'  ARABIC LETTER KAF       <- 2
U+646  'ن'  ARABIC LETTER NOON
U+627  'ا'  ARABIC LETTER ALEF
U+631  'ر'  ARABIC LETTER REH
```

The second string contains the characters:

```
U+641  'ف'  ARABIC LETTER FEH
U+631  'ر'  ARABIC LETTER REH
U+6CC  'ی'  ARABIC LETTER FARSI YEH <- 1
U+62F  'د'  ARABIC LETTER DAL
U+648  'و'  ARABIC LETTER WAW
U+646  'ن'  ARABIC LETTER NOON
U+6A9  'ک'  ARABIC LETTER KEHEH     <- 2
U+646  'ن'  ARABIC LETTER NOON
U+627  'ا'  ARABIC LETTER ALEF
U+631  'ر'  ARABIC LETTER REH
```

The characters in the third and seventh positions (marked as `<- 1` and `<- 2`) are not the same.

Comment: Ooh how did you generate this?

Comment: @Sammitch Using a Perl script I wrote a while back for answering questions like this one: https://gist.github.com/duskwuff/f7e15545df91d5608b14ed94cbb747eb

Comment: Ahh neat. I sniffed around and `intl` has this functionality as of PHP7: http://php.net/manual/en/intlchar.charname.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$wordd1='فريدونكنار';
$wordm2='فریدونکنار';
$result=strcmp($wordd1,$wordm2);
       if($result===0){
    echo 'ok'; 
}else{
    echo 'no';
}
```

The strcmp() function compares two strings.
The strcmp() function is binary-safe and case-sensitive.this function returns 0, the two strings are equal.

Comment: see here for more....http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_string_strcmp

Comment: Did you test it with this values here in the post? If not do it here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Comment: i thik encoding is not major problem for question owner.`

Comment: Go test it! My answer works, if i test your version, it will not!

Comment: either use ` if($result===0` or ` if($result==0` try.

Comment: Sorry, but you code has an SYNTAX error, it wont work at all. Look at`$result=strcmp($wordd1,$wordm2));` Im out.

Comment: That still doesn't work -- you can't add extra parentheses like that in a function call. Even with the syntax error fixed, it still says (correctly, BTW) that the strings are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your language works, but it seems you've got look-alike characters in your string.

```
function illustrate_bytes($str1, $str2) {
    for( $i=0; $i<strlen($str1); $i++ ) {
        printf("%02x %08d : %02x %08d : %s\n",
            ord($str1[$i]), decbin(ord($str1[$i])),
            ord($str2[$i]), decbin(ord($str2[$i])),
            $str1[$i] === $str2[$i] ? 'same' : 'diff');
    }
}

illustrate_bytes('ﻑﺮﻳﺩﻮﻨﻜﻧﺍﺭ', 'ﻑﺭیﺩﻮﻧکﻥﺍﺭ');
```

Output:

```
d9 11011001 : d9 11011001 : same
81 10000001 : 81 10000001 : same
d8 11011000 : d8 11011000 : same
b1 10110001 : b1 10110001 : same
d9 11011001 : db 11011011 : diff
8a 10001010 : 8c 10001100 : diff
d8 11011000 : d8 11011000 : same
af 10101111 : af 10101111 : same
d9 11011001 : d9 11011001 : same
88 10001000 : 88 10001000 : same
d9 11011001 : d9 11011001 : same
86 10000110 : 86 10000110 : same
d9 11011001 : da 11011010 : diff
83 10000011 : a9 10101001 : diff
d9 11011001 : d9 11011001 : same
86 10000110 : 86 10000110 : same
d8 11011000 : d8 11011000 : same
a7 10100111 : a7 10100111 : same
d8 11011000 : d8 11011000 : same
b1 10110001 : b1 10110001 : same
```

So the look-alikes are:

- `\xd9\x8a`:"ي" and `\xdb\x8c`:"ی"
- `\xd9\x83`:"ك" and `\xda\xa9`:"ک"

Answer (score 1):

There are two characters in Persian that each have two different character values, where the second value come from Arabic characters.

First is `ی` and `ي`.

The other one is `ک` and `ك`.

You have to replace all occurrences of the second one with the first one.

one example code is: 
`$str = str_replace('ی','ي',$str);`

Answer (score 0):

Use a function to replace similar looking characters then compare two strings.

```
function replaceSimilarChars($srting)
{

    $srting = str_replace('ي', 'ی', $srting);
    $srting = str_replace('ك', 'ک', $srting);
    // any other replacement 
    return $srting;
}
```